# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python

**Erro:**

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

**Código:**

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
y_pred = y_pred.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
```

Em `y_pred = y_pred.reshape(xx.shape)` há esse erro, o que fazer?

Comment: Aparentemente `y_pred` é uma tupla e você esperava que não fosse. Então o que pode fazer é investigar porque `y_pred` é uma tupla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque o .reshape é um método apenas da array do NumPy.
Então por algum motivo você armazenou as predições do algoritmo dentro de uma tupla ao invés de um array do numpy.
você pode fazer o seguinte procedimento e tentar de novo.

```
y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
```

Para verificar o tipo de objeto que você esta lidando você pode utilizar por exemplo:

```
type(y_pred)
```

Caso de algum problema observe como que você esta fazendo a predição com o algoritmo.